# Swift - How to extract all values with same key names

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, decodable

having looked at several posts I didn't find what I was looking for. I hope this post will help me.

I use the api of CoinDesk, what I'm trying to do now is to retrieve in the answer all the codes (EUR, USD, GBP) but I can't get all the assets.

```
    {
  "time": {
    "updated": "Feb 20, 2021 19:48:00 UTC",
    "updatedISO": "2021-02-20T19:48:00+00:00",
    "updateduk": "Feb 20, 2021 at 19:48 GMT"
  },
  "disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
  "chartName": "Bitcoin",
  "bpi": {
    "USD": {
      "code": "USD",
      "symbol": "&#36;",
      "rate": "57,014.5954",
      "description": "United States Dollar",
      "rate_float": 57014.5954
    },
    "GBP": {
      "code": "GBP",
      "symbol": "&pound;",
      "rate": "40,681.1111",
      "description": "British Pound Sterling",
      "rate_float": 40681.1111
    },
    "EUR": {
      "code": "EUR",
      "symbol": "&euro;",
      "rate": "47,048.5582",
      "description": "Euro",
      "rate_float": 47048.5582
    }
  }
}
```

here's how I'm going to get the data

public class NetworkManager {

```
static public func fetchBPI() {
    let url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("✅ Success ✅")
            if let json = response.data {
                do {
                    let data = try JSON(data: json)
                    print(data)
                    
                    let context = PersistentContainer.context
                    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "BPI", in: context)
                    let newObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
                    
                    //Date Formatter
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
                    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: data["time"]["updated"].rawValue as! String)
                    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
                    let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: date ?? Date())
                    
                    newObject.setValue(timeStamp, forKey: "time")
                    newObject.setValue(data["chartName"].rawValue, forKey: "chartName")
                    newObject.setValue(data["bpi"]["EUR"]["symbol"].rawValue, forKey: "symbol")
                    newObject.setValue(data["bpi"]["EUR"]["rate"].rawValue, forKey: "rate")
                    newObject.setValue(data["bpi"]["EUR"]["code"].rawValue, forKey: "code")
                    
                    do {
                        try context.save()
                        print("✅ Data saved ✅")
                    } catch let error {
                        print(error)
                        print("❌ Saving Failed ❌")
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print("❌ Error ❌")
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

}

I would like to get in the bpi key all the codes and put them in a list to use them.

Comment: It’s not clear what the issue is with your code, could you add a clearer description of your actual problem to the question?

Comment: I would like to get some api (EUR,USD,GBP) and put them in a list to use them later, and currently, in my request I only get EUR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle the json here in my opinion is to treat the content under "bpi" as a dictionary instead.

```
struct CoinData: Codable {
    let time: Time
    let chartName: String
    let bpi: [String: BPI]
}

struct BPI: Codable {
    let code: String
    let rate: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code
        case rate = "rate_float"
    }
}

struct Time: Codable {
    let updated: Date

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case updated = "updatedISO"
    }
}
```

I have removed some unnecessary (?) properties and also note that I made `updatedISO` in `Time` into a `Date` if that might be useful since it's so easy to convert it.

To properly decode this use `try` with a `do/catch` so you handle errors properly.

Here is an example of that where I also loop over the different currencies/rates

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
    let result = try decoder.decode(CoinData.self, from: data)

    print(result.time.updated)
    let coins = result.bpi.values
    for coin in coins {
        print(coin)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Output:

> 2021-02-20 19:48:00 +0000
> BPI(code: "GBP", rate: 40681.1111)
> BPI(code: "USD", rate: 57014.5954)
> BPI(code: "EUR", rate: 47048.5582)

Comment: What do mean with adding it to a list?

Comment: But you have that in `coins` in my example above. I am not sure what codes and rates you talk about.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to assign the values of the dictionary to the property. Try `bpi = result.bpi`

Answer (score -1):

You should use objects to represent the data from the server. It would be something like this:

```
struct CoinData: Codable {
    let time: Time
    let disclaimer, chartName: String
    let bpi: BPI
}

struct BPI: Codable {
    let usd, gbp, eur: Eur

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case usd = "USD"
        case gbp = "GBP"
        case eur = "EUR"
    }
}

struct Eur: Codable {
    let code, symbol, rate, eurDescription: String
    let rateFloat: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code, symbol, rate
        case eurDescription = "description"
        case rateFloat = "rate_float"
    }
}

struct Time: Codable {
    let updated: String
    let updatedISO: String
    let updateduk: String
}
```

Than when you download the data you parse it like this:

```
let coinData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(CoinData.self, from: jsonData)
coinData?.bpi.eur  // Access EUR for instance
```

**UPDATE**:

Simple demo to demonstrate the parsing using the data you get from your server:

```
let dataFromServer = "{\"time\":{\"updated\":\"Feb 20, 2021 21:02:00 UTC\",\"updatedISO\":\"2021-02-20T21:02:00+00:00\",\"updateduk\":\"Feb 20, 2021 at 21:02 GMT\"},\"disclaimer\":\"This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org\",\"chartName\":\"Bitcoin\",\"bpi\":{\"USD\":{\"code\":\"USD\",\"symbol\":\"&#36;\",\"rate\":\"56,689.8367\",\"description\":\"United States Dollar\",\"rate_float\":56689.8367},\"GBP\":{\"code\":\"GBP\",\"symbol\":\"&pound;\",\"rate\":\"40,449.3889\",\"description\":\"British Pound Sterling\",\"rate_float\":40449.3889},\"EUR\":{\"code\":\"EUR\",\"symbol\":\"&euro;\",\"rate\":\"46,780.5666\",\"description\":\"Euro\",\"rate_float\":46780.5666}}}"

do {
    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(CoinData.self, from: dataFromServer.data(using: .utf8)!)
    print(json.bpi.eur)  // Will print EUR object
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: @jocewl where you parse your data from the server if let json = response.data { } that's what you need. So you put there "json". `try? JSONDecoder().decode(CoinData.self, from: json)`

Comment: yes, that's correct. But the JSON what you posted in your question is correct ? It is the one that is printed when you do `print(data)` ?

Comment: @jocewl I changed the `updatedISO` value from Date to String, and tested it in the playground, it should work

Comment: @jocewl as I wrote I updated my answer and you should update your code also. Just copy paste again the whole code and it will work.

Comment: you should put there `json`

Comment: `try? JSONDecoder().decode(CoinData.self, from: json)`