Convert JSON with variable property name to Swift object
How can I convert this response:
{"base":"USD","amount":1,"result":{"EUR":0.92,"rate":0.92251},"ms":1}

to Swift response model, not to hardcode EUR as property name and just use String type instead of “EUR”?
struct CurrencyConversionResult: Codable {
    let base: String
    let amount: Double
    let result: Result
    let ms: Int
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let EUR: Double
    let rate: Double
}

This works, but only if response has EUR. If currency is changed, model needs to be updated. Is there a way to give type(String) as currency name instead of actual currency name?

Off the top of my head, I think you need to make result a Dictionary, ie let result: [String: Double] or some such.  You could make EUR (calling it something else) an enum of expected values with a unknown case - but you'd have to manually parse it for example

And an example of using a dictionary is https://stackoverflow.com/a/66303779/92238390

Do not add the "solution" as an edit to the question. If you have an answer, put it in the Answer field.
